# I need to use a splat operator within a PHP docblock and cannot figure out how to escape the character

Tags: php, escaping, codeception, splat, docblocks

I am using codeception and running multiple sets of example data. 
I am sending in multiple accept headers, one of which is `"*/*"`.

so the example code is:

```
   /**
     * My description of the test
     *
     * GET a/path/i/am/testing
     *
     * @example ["*/*", 200]
     * @example ["application/json", 200]
     * @example ["text/html", 200]
     *
     */
```

I have tried single quotes within the double, I have tried double within single, I have tried concatenating each piece, I have tried backslash, I have tried Unicode.
PHP thinks the splat is speaking to the docblock. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try with backslash? Like this? `@example ["*\/*", 200]` (incidentally, "splat operator" in PHP generally refers to the `...` operator rather than an asterisk)

Answer (score 0):

try {@*} instead of */

```
 * @example ["{@*}*", 200]
should be interpreted as
* @example ["*/*", 200]
```